# Matching string with preg_match

Tags: php

I have the following string formats: "$ 3.20" or "$ 10.34". I want to verify with preg_match if the string is exactly this type of a format.

Any suggestions are appreciated?

Comment: I'd suggest [trying something](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
if (preg_match('/\$\s[\d]+\.[\d]{2}/', $text)){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thx works great. I am not as good with those regexp stuff.